# I have implemented AfterReceiveRequest method (from IDispatchMessageInspector) and within that want to verify if request is valid?

Tags: c#, wcf

In my Client before calling the service i added a token (guid) to the request before sending to wcf service.

```
AfterReceiveRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel, System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext instanceContext)
```

Within this method, I want to verify if the request header has the token(guid) that was added in the client. So i used this part of code here:

```
Guid securityTokenId = request.Headers.GetHeader<Guid>("Token", "System");
```

If in any case this "Token" is not found in the header will my `securityTokenId` return `Guid.Empty`? or what does it return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there's no header with that name / namespace, you'll get an exception (`MessageHeaderException`) in the call to GetHeader. If you don't want to deal with exceptions, you can first see if such a header exists (using the `FindHeader` method), then if it returns a non-negative value, get the corresponding header.

```
public class StackOverflow_8854137
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ITest
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string Echo(string text);
    }
    public class Service : ITest
    {
        public string Echo(string text)
        {
            return text;
        }
    }
    class MyBehavior : IEndpointBehavior, IDispatchMessageInspector
    {
        public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {
        }

        public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
        {
        }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
        {
            endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(this);
        }

        public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
        {
        }

        public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
        {
            try
            {
                Guid tokenId = request.Headers.GetHeader<Guid>("Token", "System");
                Console.WriteLine("Token: {0}", tokenId);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", e.GetType().FullName, e.Message);
            }

            return null;
        }

        public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
        {
        }
    }
    public static void Test()
    {
        string baseAddress = "http://" + Environment.MachineName + ":8000/Service";
        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri(baseAddress));
        ServiceEndpoint endpoint = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ITest), new BasicHttpBinding(), "");
        endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new MyBehavior());
        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Host opened");

        ChannelFactory<ITest> factory = new ChannelFactory<ITest>(new BasicHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress(baseAddress));
        ITest proxy = factory.CreateChannel();
        Console.WriteLine(proxy.Echo("No token"));

        using (new OperationContextScope((IContextChannel)proxy))
        {
            OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(MessageHeader.CreateHeader("Token", "System", Guid.NewGuid()));
            Console.WriteLine(proxy.Echo("With token"));
        }

        ((IClientChannel)proxy).Close();
        factory.Close();

        Console.Write("Press ENTER to close the host");
        Console.ReadLine();
        host.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does implementing IDisptachMessageInspector and change of endpoint behaviors support for all kind of bindings like Http, TCP or namedPipes?

Comment: Carlos, Can you please post web.config for your article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/04/19/wcf-extensibility-message-inspectors.aspx                  
That was very helpful.

Comment: Re: the first question: message inspectors work regardless of the binding. For the second, the code in that post is self-hosted, and all the service setup is done in code. I actually (personally) don't like using web.config, you can see more about it at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/06/14/wcf-extensibility-servicehostfactory.aspx.

Comment: Thanks Carlos. This links are very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        var i = request.Headers.FindHeader(TOKEN_HEADER_NAME, TOKEN_HEADER_NAMESPACE);
        string token;
        if (i >= 0)
        {
            token = request.Headers.GetHeader<string>(i);
        }else
        {
            token = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            request.Headers.Add(MessageHeader.CreateHeader(TOKEN_HEADER_NAME, TOKEN_HEADER_NAMESPACE, token));
        }

        return token;
    }
```